# How to Update a column value with a pseudo column in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have one table in oracle 12c db where one column is **varchar2** data type but the values are in **DATE** format. and by some mistake there are two different type of format mixed.
Basically i have to change the format there and make all values similar.
right format is **"2018-11-21-02.57.26.00"** but some values are like this : **"11/21/2018 20:03:10.066414"** 
We need all values should be like right format. Need to prepare one update statement for this.

[image: Sample]

I have prepared the select statement like this. **Create_TS** should be updated as **Create_TS_NEW** only for those rows where CREATE_TS has '%/%'
I need to know if i can update those rows in table with Pseudo column like **Create_TS_NEW**

[image]

Comment: And at the end of making the data consistent, you're going to convert the column to be TIMESTAMP datatype, right? (Please say "yes", please say "yes"!) If you do that, you won't have any more format issues, although you will need to change code that inserts into the table (which is hopefully encapsulated in stored procedures somewhere!)

Comment: no no .. my CREATE_TS column data type will be **varchar 2** ... i am just changing the format of date value from '/' to '-' with proper format. that's all....

Comment: i need an update sql which can change correct the values with correct format

Comment: So what's to stop someone else from putting wrongly formatted data into that column?

Comment: actually this data showing in one report where this is badly appearing. so its client requirement to display properly. :)

Comment: I understand that, and I'm not trying to be pedantic here, but something put the data in with the wrong format. If it's happened before, what's to stop it happening again? If your column was of TIMESTAMP format, you don't have to worry about it being stored in the wrong format, you just have retrieve it and convert it to a string with the correct format. I guess that's outside of the remit of your current requirement, but I highly recommend you raise it with your superiors as something to look at in the future.

Comment: my problem here is not that date format..... assume it is any format of some combination of characters... as my column data type is varchar2 only.. i cannot change that...... the data loaded in wrong format i need to fix that.
if the format is "ABC/DEF/000" and i want to be like "ABC-DEF-000".

Answer (score 1):

First Try to find out value with slash (/) then convert it into date format.

```
     SELECT 
        CREATE_TS,
        CASE WHEN  INSTR(CREATE_TS,'/')>0 THEN TO_DATE(SUBSTR(CREATE_TS,1,19),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
        ELSE TO_DATE(SUBSTR(CREATE_TS,1,19),'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24-MI-SS') end default_date_format,

        to_char(CASE WHEN  INSTR(CREATE_TS,'/')>0 THEN TO_DATE(SUBSTR(CREATE_TS,1,19),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
        ELSE TO_DATE(SUBSTR(CREATE_TS,1,19),'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24-MI-SS') end,'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24-MI-SS') CREATE_TS_new 
    FROM Table_
```

Just put derived column in update statement that will enough to update the required format.

```
Update Table_ set create_ts=
to_char(CASE WHEN  INSTR(CREATE_TS,'/')>0 THEN TO_DATE(SUBSTR(CREATE_TS,1,19),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
        ELSE TO_DATE(SUBSTR(CREATE_TS,1,19),'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24-MI-SS') end,'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24-MI-SS') ;
```

Comment: i also made the create ts new column in my screenshot with substr fn...to make the expected format. but i need an **update statement** where i can update the same table with this defined column

Comment: Simply put that derived column in update statement that will works fine.

Comment: yes that works... i have used my own derived column in my update statement and it worked... thanks... :)